# jquery cycle "allowPagerClickBubble: true" not quite working

Tags: jquery, anchor, hyperlink, cycle

I want my page anchors to work as menu links so I used this code:

```
$(function() {
 $('#slideshow').cycle({
  slideExpr: 'img',      
  fx:     'fade',
  speed:  2000,
  timeout: 4000,
  pager:  '#nav',
  pagerEvent: 'mouseover',
  pauseOnPagerHover: true,
  pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
   // return sel string for existing anchor
   return '#nav li:eq(' + (idx) + ') a';
  },
  allowPagerClickBubble: true
    });
});
```

If you click the right mouse button, you can choose to open the links and they do open just fine but a normal left button click does nothing. The thing is, they WERE working so I went to work on supposedly unrelated parts of the website and at some point the left mouse button click stopped working. Any ideas what I might have done? Left button clicking still works for everything else on the site so its not some global setting. And its same across Firefox, IE, Opera, Safari, and Chrome.....

The cycle is here if my explanation is not clear: http://www.mcguirenaturals.ca/index.php

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Double-check the version number of your jQuery Cycle plugin. It looks like you are using 2.72. You'll need 2.80 or greater in order to use the allowPagerClickBubble property: http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/changes.txt